# SQL 2008 sp_getapplock transaction slowness

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, transactions, locking

Sorry - i'm not sure if this has been addressed before (i couldn't find anything relevant - please guide me)

I'm not a SQL guy, but trying to manage the SQL database & fix ongoing issues until the new SQL developer shows up. So please excuse my silly questions.

We have a stored procedures which does the following..

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

BEGIN TRAN

EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource=DBLock_100, @LockMode='Exclusive', @LockOwner='Transaction', @DbPrincipal = N'dbo';

-- SELECTS, UPDATES, DELETES, INSERTS ETC... on a few tables (nothing fancy, simple queries)

COMMIT TRAN
```

My Questions...

1. Am i right in understanding that sp_getapplock will create a lock with a name DBLock_100?
2. Is it creating a lock on the entire database? or only the tables that it will access in the codes further below?
3. Can other SP, query etc... still access the tables that is being used by the above SP? with and without NOLOCK?
4. Will the above lock be released automatically once we COMMIT TRAN?
5. All other SP, query will be on hold until the above SP either commits or rollsback?

I'm just trying to understand what the applock & transaction are doing here. Because alot of clients are experiencing slowness especially when the above SP is being executed & the SP does take a long time to execute (and we will eventually get that tuned once the new guy shows up)

Thanks in advance,
Joseph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am i right in understanding that sp_getapplock will create a lock with
>   a name DBLock_100?

It creates an application lock on the resource labelled "DBLock_100". Nothing else. The only thing that code will block is other attempts to acquire the same application lock.

i.e. concurrent calls to `sp_getapplock @Resource=DBLock_100`. So it will serialize access to that stored procedure. Any concurrent execution attempts will need to wait.

> Is it creating a lock on the entire database? or only the tables that
>   it will access in the codes further below?

Neither. The only lock taken out there is on the custom lock resource called "DBLock_100"

> Can other SP, query etc... still access the tables that is being used
>   by the above SP? with and without NOLOCK?

Yes. As long as they don't also first try and acquire the application lock called "DBLock_100". Though the UPDATES, DELETES, INSERTS ETC that you haven't shown us will still acquire locks that may block them.

> Will the above lock be released automatically once we COMMIT TRAN?

Yes. The lock will be released when you call `sp_releaseapplock` or when its owning transaction ends.

> All other SP, query will be on hold until the above SP either commits
>   or rolls back?

No. See above